# Android, recyclerview обновление данных в табах

Tags: java, android, list, recyclerview, adapter

Естть recyclerview у фрагментах. Фрагменты свою очередь в табах. Они отображают историю переписки. Когда хочу отправить сообщение, то добавляет элемент ТОЛЬКО в 1 таб, а во 2 не работает(( как исправить ? 
Код при нажатия на кнопку отправить:

```
 btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Message message = null;
                        message = new Message("text", new Date(),
                                finalDoctor.getName() + " " + finalDoctor.getSurname(), tab.getId());

                    list.add(message);
adapter.swapItems(list);
```

Адаптер для сообщений:

```
 public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Message> list;
    private Context context;
    private SimpleDateFormat fmt;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> body) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = body;
        this.fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(contactView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder vh, int position) {
        vh.text.setText(list.get(position).getText());
        vh.date.setText(fmt.format(list.get(position).getCreationDate()));
        vh.sender.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.sender)+" "+list.get(position).getSender());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void swapItems(List<Message> items) {
        this.list = items;
        Log.e("samuliak", "list size from adapter > " + list.size());
        notifyItemInserted(list.size());
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView text, date, sender;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mes_text);
            date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mes_date);
            sender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mes_sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот сам скрин экрана, для наглядности (галочка - там где работает. Крестик - где не работает):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Вот стэк ошибки:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{a171d84 position=3 id=-1, oldPos=2, pLpos:2 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:4505)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4636)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:2979)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2619)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
                                                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographe
```

**UPDATE#2**

Замечено, что если метод в адаптере изменить вот так:

```
public void swapItems(List<Message> items) {
            this.list = items;
            Log.e("samuliak", "list size from adapter > " + list.size());
            ..notifyItemInserted(list.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

тогда ошибки не будет, + добавляет элементы в конец, но отображает все в табе, в котором произошел первый клик. А в остальных без изменений.

Comment: покажите адаптер полностью

Comment: Добавил адаптер для сообщений

Comment: Вы привели текст адаптера для RecyclerView , насоклько я понимаю для одного таба, в котором и происходят изменения, получаеться что  в других табах есть  свои RecyclerView со своими адаптерами? Т.е. если два таба значит в  них 2 RecyclerView  и по два адаптера к ним?

Comment: Выходит, что так и есть! Спасибо, что прониклись проблемой!) Буду реализовать все по другому, что бы было проще.

Comment: все что вам нужно, это выполнить тоже что  вы делаете только во всех табахж

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваши табы - это фрагменты переключение между которыми реализовано с помощью адаптера, вам нужно из `TabAdapter` - взять список табов (фрагметов , если вы их используете) и на каждом таком фрагменте вызвать метод который обновляет данные.